# Access File from Log4J FileAppender programatically

Tags: java, file, log4j, appender

I have a Java application that uses the log4j logging framework. In my application I have several modules and each module creates its own log file. I start my application via command line, passing a parameter to tell my application which module it should be run. 
Lets say I have 3 modules so everytime one module gets started, all 3 log files are being created but just one is filled with information (the one from the module I just started).
I have set each File Appender to

```
...append = false
```

so that everytime I start my application I have fresh log files without old log data.

Now I have a batch file which creates a process chain, so all 3 modules are called right after the other within the batch file. 
But the problem is: 
At the end the log files from the first 2 modules are empty and only the last module stored its logs in the correct log file (of course this has to be like that because I set the append option to fasle for each file appender)

I am looking for the following solution:
When I start a module I want to check if the log file for this module is empty. If yes then I just append the logging data to this file. If there is already data in the file I want to delete the content to store the current logging data.
So at the end when I call all 3 modules (starting the application 3 times with different parameters each time) I want to have all 3 log files filled.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a fresh new log file everytime you run your program modul.

Have you considered to use a [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html)? Afer the setup of your `RollingFileAppender` you use `appender.rollOver();` in the beginning of your program to create a new log file. You can configure to keep a number of old log files with `appender.setMaxBackupIndex(int)` any older log files are getting deleted. This delegates the management of files to the framework.

A different way would be to use a [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). You can configure the time intervall for a file to roll over.

Comment: Ok thanks thats a good idea. But what if I do not know how many modules are being started? So if I have 3 modules then each log file would be created 3 times so I would have to set the MaxBackupIndex to 3. But I use a variable number of modules in later times.

Comment: each modul uses it's own Appender. so you create 3 log files only once. If you restart just one modul the other Appenders did not get rolled over.

Comment: But I use the settings with a xml configuration file because I do not want to create the appenders programatically

Comment: And another problem is, that I have to set the log files at the very first of my application (even before I start my main method) like this:
`System.setProperty("main.log", pathToLogFiles + "overview.log");
  System.setProperty("import.log", pathToLogFiles + "importToDB.log");
  System.setProperty("runJdbcConn.log", pathToLogFiles + "runJDBCconnector.log");
  System.setProperty("testJdbcConn.log", pathToLogFiles + "testJDBCconnector.log");`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly then the RollingFileAppender would create 3 log files for each module (assumed that I start 3 modules)
So lets say I have the following modules with the appropriate log files in brackets:

```
Module 1: -import (import.log)
Module 2: -parsing (parsing.log)
Module 3: -deletion (deletion.log)
```

After starting modul 1 I would have the following files + their sizes:

```
import.log (size >0)
parsing.log (empty)
deletion.log (empty)
```

Currently after starting the second modul I would have:

```
import.log (empty)
parsing.log (size >0)
deletion.log (empty)
```

When I would use the RollingFileAppender I would have the following after starting the second module:

```
import1.log (empty)
import.log (size >0)
parsing1.log (empty)
parsing.log (size >0)
deletion.log (empty)
```

But I want to have the following after starting 2 of the available 3 modules

```
import.log (size >0)
parsing.log (size >0)
deletion.log (empty)
```